# Convert curl POST to python requests

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I am using a curl POST to test out the API of [tipboard](https://github.com/allegro/tipboard) on my system. I was able to successfully send a POST to the board using:

```
curl https://** SECRET **/api/v0.1/** SECRET **/push -X POST -d "tile=big_value" -d "key=t_out" -d 'data={"title": "Outside Temperature", "description": "Temperature gathered by DS18B20 sensor", "big-value": "24.4 °C"}'
```

As the script which shall be used in the end is based on Python, I did some research and found the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) python library.

I transformed my curl request into the following code:

```
payload = {'title': 'big_value', 'key': 't_out', 'data': '"title": "Outside Temperature", "description": "Temperature gathered by DS18B20 sensor", "big-value": "24.4 °C"'}
r = requests.post("https://** SECRET **/api/v0.1/** SECRET **/push", data=payload)
print(r.text)
print(r.status_code, r.reason)
```

Which gives me the following error code:

```
There is no 'tile' field in your request.
(400, 'Bad Request')
```

I assume that my payload is not setup correctly, most likely the issue is, that I am only sending one "data" object when using Python rather than sending multiple "data elements" like with curl.

How can I equally transform my curl request into the Python variant?

Edit:

Following Dan Lowe's hint that I had a 'title' rather than 'tile' in my request lead me further with a different error using the following (edited) code:

```
payload = {'tile': 'big_value', 'key': 't_out', 'data': '"title": "Outside Temperature", "description": "Temperature gathered by DS18B20 sensor", "big-value": "24.4 °C"'}
r = requests.post("https://dev-01.linuxmind.de/api/v0.1/46d7213bd81d441783dc9ab77e5515c2/push", data=payload)
print(r.text)
print(r.status_code, r.reason)
```

Error:

```
Invalid JSON data.

(400, 'Bad Request')
```

Comment: Your curl code sets `tile=big_value` but in the Python code you have it as `title`, not `tile`.

Comment: Your data parameter needs to be another python dictionary, not a string

Comment: Take a look at this answer.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/29687915/2308683

Comment: @DanLowe fixed this issue, please see edited question.

Comment: @cricket_007 works like a charm, but that's almost like cheating ;) Thanks though

Comment: Welcome. Only took a simple "curl to requests" Google search

Answer (score 1):

Convert `data` object to post as string not as `dict`. You can do this by

```
data = json.dumps(payload)
```